# Is there a way to rotate 3D arrays in Julia?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, julia

I am trying to rotate a 3D array in julia as if it represents a physical object in 3D space.  Essentially, I want to know if there is a way to rotate an array by increments of 90 degrees along the x-, y-, and/or the z-axis.

In 2D it would be something like this if I were to rotate counter-clockwise...

```
1 2 3           3 6 9
4 5 6   ----->  2 5 8
7 8 9           1 4 7
```

I would want the same logic to apply in 3D as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For two-dimensional Matrices you have functions such as `rotl90`, `rotr90` and `rot180`. Those can be combined with `mapslices` to get the desired effect. For an example below is a rotation over dimensions `1` and `2` for each cut of array in the dimension `3`.

```
julia> A=collect(reshape(1:27,3,3,3))
3×3×3 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  4  7
 2  5  8
 3  6  9

[:, :, 2] =
 10  13  16
 11  14  17
 12  15  18

[:, :, 3] =
 19  22  25
 20  23  26
 21  24  27


julia> mapslices(rotr90,A,dims=[1,2])
3×3×3 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 3  2  1
 6  5  4
 9  8  7

[:, :, 2] =
 12  11  10
 15  14  13
 18  17  16

[:, :, 3] =
 21  20  19
 24  23  22
 27  26  25
```

Comment: Great answer, even though I have no clue what you would need this for.

Comment: It is not the answer that is great - it is the flexibility of the Julia language!